# How do I copy after I do emacs -nw

Tags: emacs, terminal

After I remotely login via ssh, I normally start an emacs client with the command `emacs -nw`. But when I am editing a file, I can select text using Ctrl-Space and then moving the cursor to the point where I want to copy. But after that, Alt-W to copy does not work at all.

If I right click on the selected text(which I selected using Ctrl-Space and moving my cursor), the copy command in the context menu is greyed out.

However, if I use the mouse and select text, I can copy ( either by Alt-W or via right clicking the selected text and choosing Copy from the context menu)

I tried Esc-W but that did not work either. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: I don't think this is really enough information to tell what's wrong, but my first guess would be that the system that you're sshed into uses a different key than Alt for meta. Try using Esc-w instead and see if that helps.

Comment: edited the question. I ssh into Amazon EC2 cluster

Comment: Try **Esc-w** b.t.w emacs has a [xterm-mouse-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text_002dOnly-Mouse.html)

Comment: I prefer to use TRAMP rather than emacs -nw.  This lets you have emacs running locally, so you can have a GUI and other nice things.

Comment: +1 for Tramp. To login as sudo to a remote machine, the syntax is    [ C-xC-f] /ssh:user@server|sudo:server:/home/user/file RET  (src: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/TRAMP)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the meta-key isn't setup properly to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  You can use <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> to copy instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use your terminal emulator's copy keybinding, i.e. Ctrl-Shift-c with gnome-terminal/Terminator/… or un-set its M-w shortcut in the preferences ?

Or use evil-mode and copy with 'y'…

or call M-x cua-copy-region when you have highlighted text…